# jpeg image colours look different in FF, Chrome + Safari

Tags: jpeg, colors

We seem to be experiencing issues with some of our jpeg product images  displaying colours differently across different browsers. (When wrong, they look as if their hues have been shifted and vibrancy has been turned up)

IE11 looks to be showing the correct colours we'd expect, but FF, Chrome and in some instances Safari (iPhone5s and iPad2) are showing the weird versions of our colours?

[image]

Not sure if the image code above words so [here is the image url](http://www.galttoys.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Two-in-One-Playnest-Box-3D.jpg) from our blog

Comment: Apologies if this is not the best exchange for this question, wasn't too sure which was best and as it's showing in the browser i thought i'd plum for this one.

Comment: I can confirm that that image does not look correct in Firefox for me.   I'm not sure if it is the cause of the issue, but it has a header that says that it is black and white.      If I open it with the GIMP it looks correct.  If I then export it to a different JPEG file and open it in firefox it looks correct.

Comment: On Windows? On FreeBSD, my workstation, they look the same with Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @Rob I'm on windows but my colleagues see it on their mac's also.

Comment: I forgot to mention that they look the same but like the one on the right.

Comment: Yes FF, Chrome & Safari look like the one of the right. IE looks like the one of the left.

Comment: Sorry but due to the nature of your problem, this question is considered off-topic because it is related to graphic design and ux issues (we have stacks for these). Normally we would migrate questions across but in this instance we have not because there is already similar questions and answers in various forms on the receiving. Your issue is related to Color Profiles, see: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9208/what-should-i-do-regarding-color-profile-when-designing-for-the-web

Comment: On my phone it's also showing the bad colors...

Comment: Yes, it will do... the browsers are using colour correction. You need to research colour profiles.